# Why does Mocha not restart Express correctly when I use --watch mode?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, supertest

I want to run tests on the API routes of my Express App. I use Mongoose and it's Schemas for DB operations. This is my Setup of the test (it runs successfully first, but then fails when it reloads...):

```
const request = require('supertest');
// this loads the whole express app
const app = require('../../server');

describe('[Auth]', function () {
  it('returns 401 with invalid credentials', function (done) {
    request(app)
      .post('/auth/login')
      .field('email', 'invalidMail')
      .field('password', 'invalidPassword')
      .expect('Content-Type', contentType)
      .expect(401, done);
  }
}
```

This test is successfull when I start mocha. I start it in `--watch mode` and whenever I save a file and mocha restarts the test i get the following error:

```
MongooseError: Cannot overwrite `user` model once compiled.
    at Mongoose.model (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:376:13)
    ...
```

What I tried is connecting and disconnecting Mongoose in the `before` and `after` hooks but that didn't change anything.

Seems to me that Mocha is just reloading my app without stopping it first. What am I missing here? What's the best practice?

Comment: I want to know this too. I can ctrl-c and restart and all tests pass.. but if I save a file it throws this error.

Comment: Thas was a while ago and I actually didn' find an answer. I solved it tho, by not using Mocha anymore. It worked great with Tape (https://github.com/substack/tape) and also with Jest (https://facebook.github.io/jest/)

Comment: I've seen a similar behaviour with Hydra and TypeORM, it just reloads without stoping them.